# Why HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name might have value before user signed in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, kerberos

For context: I am working with .Net Framework 4.6.1 ASP.Net app deployed in IIS. Inside app we had implemented SSO authentication with Kerberos (that flow with HTTP 401 and `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` header in the response, which is intercepted by someone in between app server and browser, however I do not understand who is this interceptor, and can not debug it).

The issue is, right after I am resetting session, I see in logs that during processing of the first following request, the value of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is already exist (and it is the wrong value, representing Active Directory or Windows username, not the username we using inside application). I can't see any data looking like this username in the request in browser's `Network` tab.

I tried to perform session reset on client side (clear cookie in browser) and on server side by calling API that executes:

```cs
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
httpContext.Session.Clear();
httpContext.Session.Abandon();
Roles.DeleteCookie();
```

I also see configuration item in `web.config`, that I do not understand: `defaultProxy`.

So, where did value of `Identity.Name` comes from? How can I make ASP.Net finally forget it? How this value can be matched with request even before I get any session cookie?

P.S. In my local environment without that Kerberos thing I am not facing this issue: the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` value stays empty until authentication is completed.

UPD: I managed to find out the origin of this value. It comes from windows authentication (NTLM), which enabled in this funny app, and kerberos sits on top of it. Now I am looking for way to override Identity value after kerberos authentication. Is it possible?

Comment: AFAIR kerberos is header-based, deleting cookies or session has nothing to do with it. If the server returns 401 with WWW-Authenticate, then there's the handshake between the browser and the server and ultimately you end up with 200 from the server, this could be the response you see in the network tab. The negotiated value cannot be dropped or overridden afaik. If you close the browser and reopen it, the 401 kicks in again and you end up with the very same user.

Comment: Not sure then what you mean by *value stays empty until authentication is completed* as the very first moment your ASP.NET server processes the request (and you can inspect the context.user.identity.name) is **after** the kerberos handshake.

Comment: @WiktorZychla First, I am not seeing 401 response in browser. No Authorization header is sent after clearing session. The kerberos handshake starts in one particular point in app code, some requests (to GET login form or static files, for examples) can be processed before authentication, which is were I am seeing this strange behavior.

Comment: Actually, I just managed to find out the origin of this value. It comes from windows authentication (NTLM), which enabled in this funny app, and kerberos sits on top of it. Now I am looking for way to override Identity value after kerberos authentication.

Comment: Weird. Although ntlm is connection based and there are no headers, you still should see the 401 handshake and easily learn which protocol is used. Have you debugged it with burp/fiddler?